# Setting a model member variable in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop

I'm using CodeIgniter and want to set a member variable for a model.

Here's how I'd expect to write the code:

```
class Person extends CI_Model {
    var $id = '';

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function set_id($id = '')
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }
}
```

and then I'd expect to call the model and set the member variable like this:

```
$person1 = $this->load->model('Person');
$person1->set_id(5000);
```

but this gives:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function set_id() on a non-object
```

I'm clearly missing some PHP or CodeIgniter language semantic here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this

```
$person1 = $this->load->model('Person');
$person1->set_id(5000);
```

to

```
$this->load->model('Person');
$this->Person->set_id(5000);
```

From [Documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html)

**Edit**

Different instance of single model

```
$this->load->model('Person', 'Person1');
$this->Person1->set_id(5000);

$this->load->model('Person', 'Person2');
$this->Person2->set_id(5000);
```

Comment: Yes, that works. How do you load 2 instances of a model then? e.g. Person1 and Person2?

Comment: Thanks - a bit of a bizarre way of creating objects but it works.

Answer (score 2):

you need to access model function using an object with the same name of your class..

> Once loaded, you will access your model functions using an object with the same name as your class:
>   $this->Model_name->function();

it should be..

```
$this->load->model('Person');
$this->Person->set_id(5000);
```

or

```
$this->load->model('Person', 'somename');
$this->somename->set_id(5000);
```

you can go through the [doc](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html) here